# Xarmain forms picker setting default value based on Id? not selected index

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In Xamrain forms how does one make the value default in the picker I have a list which is of type team.

```
public AddASessionPage(Session session)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    api = new TheHockeyLabMnHttpApi();
    Session = session;
    BindPicker();

    if (session != null)
    {
        txtName.Text = session.Name;
        var item = pickTeam.SelectedItem as Team;
        pickTeam.SelectedItem = item.Name;

        txtDateStartEntry.Text = session.StartDate.ToString();
        txtDateStartEntry.Text = session.EndDate.ToString();
    }
}
```

My List is made of

```
public  class Team
{
  public int Id { get; set; }     
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int? SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

My question is on my AddASession Page constructor How do I pic the default Yes I no could use selectedIndex but that is not how am storing am storing based on the text value in the picker.

As such

```
<Picker x:Name="pickTeam" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"></Picker>
```

Or is their another value I can save get the value of Team > Id in the xaml of the control usually asp.net has a ItemDisplayValue does xamrain have such the same?

Comment: you are treating `SelectedItem` as both a `Team` and a `string`.  It can't be both.

Comment: Well does xamrian not have a selectedValue like .net core does?

Comment: What does that have to do with what I asked?  You are trying to use two completely different types interchangably - that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your `Picker` `ItemSource` is **myData**

```
var item = myData.Where(x => x.Name == session.Name).FirstOrDefault();

pickTeam.SelectedItem = item;
```

Comment: Makes since and works in conjunction with ur answers above.